# Implement interface concretely

Tags: c#, .net

I have a generic interface like so:

```
public interface IHandler
{
    T Process<T>(IProcess process) where T : new();
}
```

At times I would like to Implement interface concretely, for example:

```
public class BoolHandler : IHandler
{
    public bool Process<bool>(IProcess process)
    {
        // Do some work - set to true or false
        return true;
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

**EDIT:
currently I could have done this:**

```
// Injecct handler in Main and work with single handler
ViewModel model = handler.Process<ViewModel>(process);
DifferentModel model = handler.Process<DifferentModel >(process);
```

With the suggestions listed I would have to do this (which I'm trying to avoid-it requires me to create bunch of handlers on the fly):

```
IHandler<ViewModel> handler = new Handler<ViewModel>();
ViewModel viewModel = handler.Process(process);

IHandler<DifferentModel> handler = new Handler<DifferentModel>(); // Create yet another handler - arrr
DifferentModel viewModel = handler.Process(process);
```

Comment: Move the parameter `T` to the `IHandler` interface and remove it from the `Process` method. Generic parameters on methods need to work uniformly for all applicable types which your implementation cannot.

Comment: Will the implementation depend on the type that provided?  If so, then the method is not "generic"

Comment: Would `BoolHandler` and the other handlers be used by the same consumer (that wants to consume them polymorphically)? If not, you can have two interfaces, a non-generic interface with a generic method, and a generic interface with a non-generic method.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample?

Comment: Is there some method that takes in a `IHandler`? e.g. `void ConsumeHandler(IHandler handler, ...)`? Would you want to pass `BoolHandler` (that wants to implement the method concretely) and other types that want to implement the generic method, interchangeably? If not, then these should have different interfaces.

Comment: Yes. I would like to have a list of there handlers and fire off one after another-ie: composite

Comment: You still haven't explained how you're planning on creating the return values from `Process`. Is `new T()` sufficient?

Comment: yes. new T() will be sufficient

Comment: So then just add `return new T();` to the end of `Process`? Your question implies the return value depends on some aspect of the `Process` method.

Comment: what if it's a bool. in case of bool implementation how would i return "false"?

Comment: `new bool()` is `false`. You won't be able to return `true` though.

Comment: Exactly, In case of bool implementation i need to be able to return true or false. Type is known, however I need to able to control the value

Comment: Please add more detail to the question. You just said `new T()` would work but this clearly isn't the case. How is the implementation of `Process` supposed to be able to construct a value of some type arbitrary type `T` specified by the caller? This isn't possible in general without resorting to reflection, so you need to describe the construction process in more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand your question (from the comment exchange), some handlers can handle any type `T` (or many types `T`) and other handlers can handle only a single type. Also, you would like to consume these handlers within one consumer polymorphically.

Here is what you can do:

Create two interfaces like this:

```
public interface IHandler //Can handle many types
{
    T Process<T>(int process);

    bool CanProcess<T>();
}

public interface IHandler<T> //Can handle a single type
{
    T Process(int process);
}
```

And then create an adapter from `IHandler<T>` to `IHandler` like this:

```
public class Adaptor<T> : IHandler
{
    private readonly IHandler<T> handler;

    public Adaptor(IHandler<T> handler)
    {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public T1 Process<T1>(int process)
    {
        if(!CanProcess<T1>())
            throw new Exception(
                "Contract violated. I cannot handle type " + typeof(T1).Name);

        return (T1)(object)handler.Process(process);
    }

    public bool CanProcess<T1>()
    {
        return typeof (T1) == typeof (T);
    }
}
```

Now, your composite can do something like this:

```
public class CompositeHandler : IHandler
{
    private readonly IHandler[] handlers;

    public CompositeHandler(params IHandler[] handlers)
    {
        this.handlers = handlers;
    }

    public T Process<T>(int process)
    {
        var handler = handlers.FirstOrDefault(h => h.CanProcess<T>());

        if(handler == null)
            throw new Exception(
                "Contract violated. I cannot handle type " + typeof(T).Name);

        return handler.Process<T>(process);
    }

    public bool CanProcess<T>()
    {
        return handlers.Any(h => h.CanProcess<T>());
    }
}
```

Now, you can adapt any `IHandler<T>` implementation to `IHandler` and use it normally as `IHandler`. For instance, you can use it as part of the composite.

Here is an example composition:

```
var service = new CompositeHandler(
    new TypeThatImplementsTheNonGenericInterface(),
    new Type2ThatImplementsTheNonGenericInterface(),
    new Adaptor<SomeType>(
        new TypeThatImplementsTheGenericInterface<SomeType>()));
```

Comment: this helped a lot!.= Thank you

Answer (score 3):

No, it is *not* possible.  Your interface states that any implementing class must have a method *where that method can be used with any type* [meeting the generic constraints].  If your class only works for, say, boolean values, then *you are not fulfilling the contract* that the interface specifies, and so the type cannot implement that interface.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this pattern

```
   public interface IHandler<T> where T : new()
    {
        T Process(IProcess process);
    }

    public interface IProcess
    {
    }

    public class BoolHandler : IHandler<bool>
    {
        public bool Process(IProcess process)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: just noticed that's what Lee said in his comment - anyway here it is written out for you

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I have to create separate handler for each Type. With what I have above I could do var result = _handler.Process<MyResult>();

Comment: @ShaneKm - How is the implementation of `Process` going to create an instance of any type you provide? (e.g. work for both `bool` and `MyResult`). This isn't possible in general (ignoring reflection) and if you're going to do that you can move the logic out of `Process` completely.

Comment: @Lee See the definition of `Activator.CreateInstance<T>` for one example.  But in the case of the interface provided, that it specifies the generic argument's type has a parameterless constructor makes constructing an instance of it to return rather easy.

Comment: @Servy - Yes they could do something like that although `new bool()` is `false` but the example  in the question returns `true` so I assume the logic is more complicated.

Comment: @Lee It may well not be something that the OP should be doing here, in fact, it most likely is not, but it's something that is not only possible, but appropriate in many cases; this just isn't one of them.  As for what the OP should be doing, we have nowhere near enough information to know, so I don't see much point in trying to guess.

Answer (score 0):

I know some will say that this is not a good practice, but it is an alternative. You can replace the generic `T` with `object` in the interface, and do some casts:

```
public interface IHandler
{
    object Process(IProcess process);
}

public class BoolHandler : IHandler
{
    object Process(IProcess process){ return true;}
}
```

It will be *something like* implementig the interface with the generic declared, but this way you promise the users that `BoolHandler` will always return a bool.