# Collection of generic handlers - is this possible?

Tags: c#, generics

Using generics is it possible to have a generic collection defined as a base type and assign instances of a sub type?   I have a simple code sample below that highlights my thinking and the line that causes the compiler error.  I know that I could create a IEventHandler marker interface and make my generic event handlers inherit from that.  This would let me store the generic types within a collection of IList, but this seems less than ideal.  Is there a way similar to the code I have below?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IEventHandler<SomeEvent1> handler1 = new SomeEvent1Handler();
            IEventHandler<SomeEvent2> handler2 = new SomeEvent2Handler();


            IList<IEventHandler<IEvent>> handlers = new List<IEventHandler<IEvent>>();
            // COMPILE ERROR - is this possible?
            handlers.Add(new SomeEvent1Handler());
        }

        public interface IEvent {

        }

        public interface IEventHandler<in TEvent> where TEvent : IEvent 
        {
            void Handle(TEvent someEvent);
        }

        public class SomeEvent1 : IEvent {
        }
        public class SomeEvent2 : IEvent {
        }

        public class SomeEvent1Handler : IEventHandler<SomeEvent1>
        {
            public void Handle(SomeEvent1 someEvent)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public class SomeEvent2Handler : IEventHandler<SomeEvent2>
        {
            public void Handle(SomeEvent2 someEvent)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: No, it wouldn't be safe. You could create a wrapper which implements `IEventHandler<IEvent>` and checks the incoming event type to `Handle` dynamically.

Comment: *"Using generics is it possible to have a generic collection defined as a base type and assign instances of a sub type?"* Yes, but It could only be done if your interface was `IEventHandler<out TEvent>`, you can't do it with `in`. if your code did work, what would you expect to happen if the next line of code was `handlers[0].Handle(new SomeEvent2());`, according to the interface `Hande` can take in any `IEvent` so the function call would be legal, `SomeEvent1Handler` would be passed a `SomeEvent2` to its `public void Handle(SomeEvent1 someEvent)` method.

Comment: Any thoughts on possible solutions to achieve what I'm trying to do or am I off track ?

Comment: @JeremyF my work around would be have the handlers just take in a `IEvent`, in the function they check if it is a type of event they don't care about they can just return from the function without doing anything.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain why not post your answer as answer?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain unfortunately the real power I'm trying to unlock is that each IEvent will be unique (properties, etc.) and I want the handlers to have strongly typed access so they can fetch what they need from the event and process it.

Comment: @JeremyF Let say you can store them somehow in a list. What will you do with that list?

Comment: @IvanStoev Dictionary<string, IEventHandler<IEvent>> is likely a more real-world example.  Basically I am trying to construct an Event Aggregator that would include a method for callers to Publish events and the goal would be that any suitable handlers for the event are found and then executed.

Comment: I guess you can store them internally as `object`. Then you would use `list.OfType<IEventHandler<TEvent>>()` to filter out the ones you have to execute for a specific `TEvent`.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40138088/2290059

Comment: @Jermey the way to do that is you make the agragator generic so you would have `Dictionary<string, IEventHandler<TEvent>>` defined in the agragator. You would use it like `MyAggrator<SomeEvent1>.AddSubscriber(handler1);` and `MyAggrator<SomeEvent1>.Publish(new SomeEvent1());`

Answer (score 0):

> Using generics is it possible to have a generic collection defined as
>   a base type and assign instances of a sub type?

Yes, but It could only be done if your interface was `IEventHandler<out TEvent>`, you can't do it with `in`.

If your code did work, what would you expect to happen if the code was

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IList<IEventHandler<IEvent>> handlers = new List<IEventHandler<IEvent>>();
        handlers.Add(new SomeEvent1Handler()); //Magicly works
        IEventHandler<IEvent> handler = handlers[0];
        handler.Handle(new SomeEvent2());
    }
```

`handler` states it allows any `IEvent` to be passed in to its `Handle` function. This would cause `SomeEvent1Handler` would be passed a `SomeEvent2` object to its `public void Handle(SomeEvent1 someEvent)` method.

My work around would be have the handlers just take in a `IEvent`, in the function they check if it is a type of event they don't care about they can just return from the function without doing anything.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IEventHandler<SomeEvent1> handler1 = new SomeEvent1Handler();
            IEventHandler<SomeEvent2> handler2 = new SomeEvent2Handler();


            IList<IEventHandler> handlers = new List<IEventHandler>();

            handlers.Add(new SomeEvent1Handler());
        }

        public interface IEvent {

        }

        public interface IEventHandler 
        {
            void Handle(IEvent someEvent);
        }

        public class SomeEvent1 : IEvent {
        }
        public class SomeEvent2 : IEvent {
        }

        public class SomeEvent1Handler : IEventHandler
        {
            public void Handle(IEvent someEvent)
            {
                var event = someEvent as SomeEvent1;
                if(event == null)
                    return;

                //Do stuff here.
            }
        }

        public class SomeEvent2Handler : IEventHandler
        {
            public void Handle(IEvent someEvent)
            {
                var event = someEvent as SomeEvent2;
                if(event == null)
                    return;

                //Do stuff here.
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done as it is not safe - if it were allowed you could do:

```
var handlers = new List<IEventHandler<IEvent>> { new SomeEvent1Handler() };
handlers[0].Handle(new SomeEvent2());
```

I suggest you create a wrapper class around a typed handler e.g.

```
public class HandlerWrapper<T> : IEventHandler<IEvent>
{
    private readonly IEventHandler<T> inner;

    public HandlerWrapper(IEventHandler<T> inner)
    {
        this.inner = inner;
    }
    public void Handle(IEvent event)
    {
        if(event is T) { inner.handle((T)event); }
        else throw new ArgumentException("Unexpected event type");
    }
}
```

You can now create an `IList<EventHandler<IEvent>>` and you will need to manage the dispatch to the correct handler dynamically.